# setListAdaptor Error in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-listfragment

I have this fragment called HomeFragment.java

The code is as follows:-

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    String username, id;
    ListView t1;
    int idno;
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        t1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.getInfo);
       if(intent.getStringExtra("username") == null)
       {
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent1);
       }
       else
       {
        username =  intent.getStringExtra("username");
        id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        idno = Integer.parseInt(id);

        new getDetails().execute(new ApiConnector());


       }



        return rootView; 



    }


    public void setListAdaptor(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        t1.setAdapter(new GetAllInfoListView(jsonArray,getActivity()));

    }

    private class getDetails extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
            return params[0].getDetails(idno);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //setListAdaptor(jsonArray);

        }


    }


}
```

There are no compilation erros.
But when I run it i get a NullPointerException at --> `t1.setAdapter(new GetAllInfoListView(jsonArray,getActivity()));`

And this is my List Adaptor class:-

```
public class GetAllInfoListView extends BaseAdapter {

    private JSONArray dataArray;
    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflator = null;

    public GetAllInfoListView(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a)
    {
        this.dataArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = a;

        inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListCell cell;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.cell_layout, null);
            cell = new ListCell();

            cell.name =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            cell.age =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_age);
            cell.city =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_city);
            cell.airline = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.airline_pick);
            cell.dep_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dep_time);
            convertView.setTag(cell);
        }
        else
        {
            cell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);

            cell.name.setText(jsonObject.getString("BKTBOARDCITY")+" - "+jsonObject.getString("BKTOFFCITY"));
            cell.age.setText(jsonObject.getString("BKTAIRLINE"));
            cell.city.setText(jsonObject.getString("BKTDEPDATE").substring(11));
            cell.dep_time.setText(jsonObject.getString("BKTDEPDATE").substring(0,11));
            String image = jsonObject.getString("BKTAIRLINE");
            if(image.equals("Air India"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.airindia);
            }
            if(image.equals("Air Costa"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.aircosta);
            }
            if(image.equals("Go Airways"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.goairways);
            }
            if(image.equals("Indian Airlines"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.indianairline);
            }
            if(image.equals("Indigo"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.indigo);
            }

            if(image.equals("Jet Airways"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.jetairways);
            }
            if(image.equals("Jet Lite"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.jetlite);
            }
            if(image.equals("Kingfisher Airlines"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.kingfisher);
            }
            if(image.equals("Paramount Airways"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.paramount);
            }
            if(image.equals("Spice Jet"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.spicejet);
            }
            if(image.equals("United Airlines"))
            {
                cell.airline.setImageResource(R.drawable.unitedairlines);
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ListCell
    {
        private TextView name;
        private TextView age;
        private TextView city;
        private ImageView airline;
        private TextView dep_time;
    }

}
```

Please help. Thanks :D

Comment: Is there a `ListView` in `R.layout.fragment_home` with `id` = `getInfo`? If so, are you _always_ calling `setAdapter()` _after_ using `findViewById` on it?

Comment: Always include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions.

Comment: Justin Jasmann is right. it seems that findViewById(R.id.getInfo) returns null. check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong i think

```
t1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.getInfo);
```

use like this

```
t1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.getInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. But if you dont mind can u explain a little in details what the problem was, because i dont want to repeat it.

Comment: you were give wrong reference to the listview if you see it properly you have inflate you layout to rootview and its means that your listview is inside that layout right now you are trying to get listview reference from getActivity its mean you are using your parent activity but not using that specific view that u have inflated